# SpooledTemporaryFile: units of maximum (in-memory) size?

Tags: python, temporary-files

The parameter `max_size` of `tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile()` is the maximum size of the temporary file that can fit in memory (before it is spilled to disk). What are the units of this parameter (bytes? kilobytes?)? The documentation (both for [Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile) and [Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile)) does not indicate this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The size is in bytes. From the [`SpooledTemporaryFile()` source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d444496e714a/Lib/tempfile.py#l505):

```
def _check(self, file):
    if self._rolled: return
    max_size = self._max_size
    if max_size and file.tell() > max_size:
        self.rollover()
```

and `file.tell()` gives a position in bytes.

I'd say that any use of the term `size` in connection with Python file objects that is *not* expressed in bytes warrants an explicit mention. All other file methods that deal in terms of `size` always work in bytes as well.

Comment: Good point, about bytes being standard. However, this is an implicit rule that requires a good knowledge of Python: I think that `SpooledTemporaryFile()` should explicitly indicate that the size is in bytes, so that *anybody* can use it, without much prior Python culture. I will open an issue on this.

Comment: @EOL: I'm not sure that that's needed; in C or Java or C# or any other language I have worked with, when dealing with a file object you deal with bytes, or for Unicode support, codepoints. Only when dealing with higher-level APIs or user interfaces do you start to see other units.

Comment: I am sure that it would not cost much to add "in bytes" in the documentation: it will arguably cost less time than the time lost by people who have the same question I had. I had this question because of one of your answers (from 2012), where you used the size 1024*10: this is extremely small, so I was really wondering if they were bytes.

Comment: Is 10Kb that small? I guess it could be, depending on how many of these you are creating and what size is typical.

Comment: Yeah, 10 Kb is very small: even smaller than 10 KB. :) More seriously, computers typically have 500,000 more memory than this, so you can see why I wasn't sure about the memory size units in `SpooledTemporaryFile()`.

Comment: @EOL but per process you get about 4GB max, which includes the whole Python program. It still depends on how many of these are going to be active at any one time as well.

Comment: The default size is set to 0. Does this mean arbitrary growth, or that it writes to disk immediately?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: arbitrary growth; see the code copied into my answer: `if max_size and file.tell() > max_size:` can only true if `max_size` is *not zero*.